# Сложение определенных столбцов в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Доброго времени суток!

Прошу помочь, искал на просторах интернета, но так и не понял как конкретно сложить именно нужные столбцы, не трогая другие.

Необходимо сложить значения столбов к примеру a,b,c,d в один и назвать к примеру его F.

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv("C:\\table_primer.csv", low_memory=False)

table=data[["ID","Period","a","b","c","d"]]

print(table)
```

вот как выводит

```
   ID  Period  a  b  c  d
0   1       2  3  4  5  6
1   2       3  4  5  6  7
```

Как вывести сложенные значения a,b,c,d под новым столбцом F, при этом не трогая ID и Period( это время), и убрать из таблицы a,b,c,d после сложения в F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [DataFrame.eval(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html), *динамически* создав формулу для суммы столбцов:

```
cols = ["a","b","c","d"]
table = table.eval("F = {}".format("+".join(cols))).drop(columns=cols)
```

результат:

```
In [32]: table
Out[32]:
   ID  Period   F
0   1       2  18
1   2       3  22
```

---

динамическое создание формулы - суммируем все столбцы, указанные в списке `cols`:

```
In [33]: "F = {}".format("+".join(cols))
Out[33]: 'F = a+b+c+d'
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а можно ли при этом оставить только значения F, удалив a,b,c,d?

Comment: @Евгений, смотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а не подскажите еще, как прописать выделение определенного периода? к примеру запись в csv 2019-11-10 07:45:00.000, там несколько дней, как выбрать с 00.00 по 00.00 след дня, то есть ровно сутки? лучше создать отдельный вопрос? я просто новичок в питоне, пытаюсь разобраться, а время поджимает(

Comment: Понял, сейчас создам.

Answer (score 3):

```
df['f'] = df[['a','b','c','d']].sum(axis=1)
```

или

```
df['f'] = df.loc[:, 'a':'d'].sum(axis=1)

   ID  Period  a  b  c  d   f
0   1       2  3  4  5  6  18
1   2       3  4  5  6  7  22
```

чтобы удалить колонки

```
df.drop(columns=['a','b','c','d'], inplace=True)
print(df)

   ID  Period   f
0   1       2  18
1   2       3  22
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а можно ли при этом оставить только значения F, удалив a,b,c,d?

Comment: `df.drop(columns=['a','b','c','d'])`